# CSV to JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to build a JSON file using python and starting with a CSV file.

The CSV file look like this :

```
a,b,tableau.c,tableau2.d,tableau2.e,tableau2.f,tableau2.g,tableau.h
11725,11741,false,N/A,true,23,N/A,false
```

So far i'm managing to convert the csv file to a JSON file and arrange it to look like this :

```
[
  {
    "a": "11725",
    "b": "11741",
    "tableau.c": "false",
    "tableau.h": "false",
    "tableau2.d": "N/A",
    "tableau2.e": "true",
    "tableau2.f": "23",
    "tableau2.g": "N/A"
  }
]
```

Using this code :

```
import csv
import json

file = "myFile.csv"
json_file = "myFile.json"
csv_rows = []

with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    title = reader.fieldnames

    for row in reader:
        csv_rows.extend([{title[i]:row[title[i]] for i in     range(len(title))}])


with open(json_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(csv_rows, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

But my wish would to get to a JSON file that look like this one :

```
[
    {
        "a": "11725",
        "b": "11741",
        "tableau": [
        { 
          "value" :"false",
          "name" : "c"
        },
        { 
          "value" :"false",
          "name" : "h"
        },
    ]
        "tableau2": [
        { 
          "value" :"N/A",
          "name" : "d"
        },
        { 
          "value" :"true",
          "name" : "e"
        },
        { 
          "value" :"23",
          "name" : "f"
        },
        { 
          "value" :"N/A",
          "name" : "g"
        },
    ]

    }
]
```

I have been looking around for answer about how to do this and found nothing so far.

Any suggestion about how to do this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your csv file look exactly like this or will there be more rows/elements in each line in the file later on? Just to clarify: `tableau` consists only elements with `"value": "false" ` and `tableau2` all the other ones?

Comment: *Aside*: Your `for row in reader` loop is redundant. Try:  `csv_rows = list(reader)`

Comment: Hi, thank for your help but Alex Hall answered the question.

Comment: Well it's not clear from your question if this answer is generalizeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
for row in reader:
    row_result = {}
    for key, value in row.iteritems():
        if '.' in key:
            tableau, name = key.split('.')
            row_result.setdefault(tableau, []).append({'value': value, 'name': name})
        else:
            row_result[key] = value
    csv_rows.append(row_result)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much ! I still need to understand precisely what you have done but it's perfect.